# 10.6.8. Can't connect to server via cmd+k or Finder menu or command line. How to connected?

Tags: snow-leopard, finder, network

My biggest problem is: <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> (`Connect to Server…`) just doesn't work (neither does it exist in the "Go" menu in Finder). When I hit <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> in Finder it just gives me an error beep (sounds more like a "boup"). I want to connect to a Windows network and it works fine on my 10.8 iMac at work (with <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> and then typing the correct adress) but doesn't on my home MacBook white with 10.6.8 running. Why does <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> not work here? Though on both machines the VPN connection works fine. How do I get the option to connect to a server via <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> back?

Next thing I tried was connecting via command line with
`mount -t smbfs //username:password@server\folder` and
`mount -t smbfs //username:password@server/folder`.

Both didn't seem to work, just gave me the message:

```
usage: mount [-dfruvw] [-o options] [-t ufs | external_type] special node
       mount [-adfruvw] [-t ufs | external_type]
       mount [-dfruvw] special | node
```

Can you help me to get connected to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/53617/connect-to-server-option-missing) has some suggestions for enabling the missing menu option (that question is about 10.7, but worth a try).

I think the command line version isn't working because you need to provide a final argument, specifying where to mount the shared directory locally.  On my 10.6.8 machine, `man mount_smbfs` gives this example:

```
mount -t smbfs //username:userpass@myserver/PUBLIC /smb/public
```

Comment: Woohoo, that one worked! Thank you!!! And as I see now, my question maybe could bet set to 'duplicate'...